# jQuery grep not working on object array but for loop does

Tags: javascript, jquery, grep

I'm following this tutorial here: http://ddmvc4.codeplex.com/ for knockout.js. This is my first go at javascript but I think I know what I'm doing so far.

I have a simple object array like so:

```
var DummyCompetition = [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Sport": 'Powerlifting',
        "Title": 'Íslandsmeistaramót í klassískum kraftlyftingum',
        "Country": 'Iceland',
        "DateStart": new Date(2014, 2, 8),
        "DateEnd": new Date(2014, 2, 8)
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Sport": 'Powerlifting',
        "Title": 'Íslandsmeistaramót í kraftlyftingum',
        "Country": 'Iceland',
        "DateStart": new Date(2014, 4, 8),
        "DateEnd": new Date(2014, 4, 8)
    }
]
```

and I try to filter id in a function like so

```
var currentCompetition = $.grep(DummyCompetition, function (c) {
        return c.Id == id;
    });

currentCompetition = new Competition(currentCompetition[0]);
```

where id is obtained from the URL `var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);`

If I run my page the javascript won't load but if I filter the array with a for loop everything works fine.

```
for (var i = 0; i < DummyCompetition.length; i++)
{
    if (DummyCompetition[i].Id == id)
    {
        var currentCompetition = new Competition(DummyCompetition[i]);
        break
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/xgQLD/

Comment: Found out what was wrong. See my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. Visual studio puts the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` line of the `_Layout.cshtml` view below the `@RenderBody()` line so it doesn't load it for the view I'm using jQuery in.

Moving it to the top where `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")` is fixes it.